# Can the efficiency of a thermodynamic cycle be worked out from a pV diagram?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

Is it true that a pV diagram of a thermodynamic cycle with a specified scale on both axes is enough to calculate its efficiency (such as the one below)? Is it the area within the shape divided by the area under the top curve?

[image: Thermal cycle pV diagram]

Comment: The efficiency is the ratio of work delivered and heat withdrawn. The work is  in your case the area of the shape.

Comment: i remember we need rigorous maths for finding efficiency for pV diagram @mrk

Comment: To get started, see as examples, the calculations shown here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/questions-on-carnots-theorem/202367#202367

Comment: Thanks. So would the efficiency be the area of the "almost triangle" (approximately 900J) devided by the area under AB (approximately 900+1000=1900J ) = 900/1900 = 0.47 ?

Comment: The efficiency can not be worked out from a pV diagram. Or pV diagram is not enough to tell you the efficiency. The area of the shape is the net work you get after a cycle (A->B->C->A). The area under the top curve in your graph is the work done by the system to the surrounding from state A to state B.

Comment: The efficiency can not be determined solely from the P-V diagram.  The efficiency is equal to the work done divided by the input heat added.  Even in the case of the Carnot cycle, work is being done during the adiabatic expansions and compressions, even though no heat is being added or removed during these steps.  If you didn't know it was a Carnot cycle, you couldn't determine the amount of heat added.  For an arbitrary reversible process, the most you can determine from the P-V diagram is the *net* amount of heat added.

Comment: In other words, the pV diagram is supposed to capture the idealized version of the engine etc. which is 100% efficient, and all the losses occur due to some things that are messy and go beyond the simple description of p,V.

Answer (score 2):

If the graph itself really is the only information that you have, then you're out of luck. But in many cases you will actually have some other information, and it may be enough to let yo solve the problem. If

- You also know the internal energy as a function of pressure and volume $E = E(P,V)$.<sup>1</sup>
- You either known the functional form of the curves in diagram or are willing to settle for an approximation to the work for each stage (numeric or from a [planimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter)).

and

- All the stages are quasi-static

then this is tractable.

The area under each segment gives you the work done on that segment, and from the end-points you compute the total change in internal energy $\Delta E$. The heat for the stage is then<sup>2</sup>
$$ Q = \Delta E - W \;, \tag{1}$$

Add all the heat from stages with positive $Q$ together and call that $Q_H$.

Add all the heat from stages with negative $Q$ together and call the absolute value of the result $Q_C$.

The efficiency is then
$$ \eta = 1 - \frac{Q_C}{Q_H} \;,$$
in the normal fashion.

---

<sup>1</sup> Keep in mind that for monatomic ideal gases $E = \frac{3}{2}PV$, and that you can use $E = \frac{5}{2}PV$ for air at STP and make fairly modest error.

<sup>2</sup> I've written equation (1) in the convention where work done *on* the system is positive. If you are using the convention that work done *by* the system is positive than it should read
$$ Q = \Delta E + W \;. \tag{1a}$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition, efficiency of a thermodynamic process, is the ratio of the total work done as output to the total heat **supplied** (and only supplied, mind it). It is very important to add only the heats that are supplied(I am specifically using plural form to emphasise on this fact) and not the net heat exchange for the process. If in the diagram, certain values(say pressure, volume etc. as in your graph) are provided with at some points, then you may surely find the efficiency. For each curve, you would need to find out whether heat is supplied or released(absolutely essential, again), and work done,which can be found out easily by using the First Law equation. By the way, PV diagrams are indeed necessary for calculating efficiency.

Comment: should be more detailed..as to where and how to find whether heat is supplied or withdrawn or neither

Comment: Hi! The first law equation is the key. You know the work done(the curve in the concerned region/process) and you can find the internal energy, by knowing the final and initial states(temperature; internal energy is a state function).You then get Q. Or in special cases like adiabatic curves whose equations are known, you know already know that there's no heat exchange.

Comment: @Ratnottam Das : how do you get the internal energy from this diagram? What would be the value?